# Inject an object into a service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now without getting to a good solution. How can I inject an object into a function, so that I can use it in there? Example:

```
angular.module(moduleName).service('myService', MyService, MyObject);
```

Here, MyObject is defined, so everything is ok. But then, inside the function, it is undefined. How can I pass the object to the function and use it in there?

```
CamundaService.$inject = ['$http'];
function CamundaService($http, MyObject) {...}
```

Injecting it as a second parameter in the array did not work and I get an error:

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider
```

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Please make your code plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular `constant`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('MyObject', {
    message: 'hello world'
});
```

Now you can inject `MyObject`.